# Should I keep creating branches or should I merge?

Tags: git

I work with a giant repository that is constantly being updated. So when I tackle a new task I create my branch and sometimes I work with it for weeks. Then it comes to my mind to pull and for some reason I have like 47 conflicts. My solution: create a new branch from the updated master branch and cherry-pick my 7 commits. I delete the old branch with all its conflicts unresolved. I do this frequently, so I wonder if is this ok? Or are there any reasons to deal with the 47 conflicts?

Comment: You should `git pull --rebase` regularly and fix conflicts early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Always update your repository w/ the origin `git fetch` or `git pull`
- If you are working with other people, or a team it's better to rebase your changes and resolve the conflicts 1 by 1 e.g. `git rebase origin/master`
- Clean off your local branches if you have time, they get outdated most of the time.
- Make sure to take advantage of Git's other features like `git stash` or `git reset`

Comment: If I make some commits and push and later I git rebase and then push again, wouldn't that cause a mess for others that are not working in my branch but made a fetch and have a remote copy of my branch?

Comment: Well that's the rule of thumb, you don't push something that isn't finished yet, either you commit small changes time to time until it's done and do a rebase / fix conflicts. You can still rebase in your local without having to push it, rebase and fix the conflicts first (if there are) then when you are ready, you can push your changes to the remote.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Yeah I heard about rewriting the git history.